# How to redirect in frappe a URL that includes parameters?

Tags: redirect, erpnext, frappe

In frappe, I am setting the redirections in `hooks.py` as follows:

```
website_redirects = [
...
{ "source": "/login", "target": "/entrar" },
```

However, I had many difficulties to setup a working redirection that included a property. For example, from `/login?redirect-to=other-page` to `/entrar?redirect-to=other-page`, the parameter was not passed.

I finally found a solution, but since I did not find any help online and spent several hours to find it, I thought I would post it here to save time to anybody facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution eventually was to combine the (barely documented) property `"match_with_query_string": True` and some regex:

```
website_redirects = [
...
{ "source": r"/login\?(.*)", "target": r"/entrar?\1", "match_with_query_string": True },
{ "source": "/login", "target": "/entrar" },
```